# Корректное использование внутренних кавычек

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
После последней строчки после нажатия "Enter" знак **->** меняется на **'>**. И не могу выполнить запрос на выполнение, идет переход на лругую строчку. Пожалуйста помогите!!!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: точку с запятой поставте

Comment: хотя там поле else еще должен быть END

Comment: @Mike, ставил, обновил вопрос

Comment: @Mike, а там from не должен быть с объявлением что такое `gr` и `st` и `surname`?

Comment: В строке ELSE 3 кавычки

Comment: @Grundy, обновил вопрос

Comment: @Mike, стоит ответом сделать я думаю:)

Comment: @Mike, просто изменить ELSE?

Comment: @Grundy Да по "опечатка или более не воспроизводится" закрывать такое надо

Comment: @MuscledBoy Ну а как вы думали. Первая кавычка открывающая, вторая закрывающая, а весь остальной текст непонятно к чему относится. Экранировать кавычки надо как и во всех других языках, обратными косыми например

Comment: @Mike, здесь скорее даже не знал про то, что кавычку в строке надо экранировать. поэтому мне кажется лучше ответом

Comment: @Grundy Проблема в том что если кто нибудь столкнется он все равно этот вопрос никогда не найдет.

Comment: @Mike, поэтому заголовок вопроса тоже стоит отредактировать :)

Comment: @Grundy Интересно на что "Как писать строки в кавычках и если они не так стоят что может выдать консоль MySQL"

Comment: @Mike, например: _как использовать одинарную кавычку внутри строки_ :)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @MuscledBoy, там Mike отвечал, а не я :)

Comment: @Mike, огромное Вам спасибо, если бы Вы не сказали, ответ на вопрос сам не нашел бы честно говоря. просто не знаешь как правильно сформулировать его)

Comment: @Mike, не сочтите за наглость, но необходим Ваш совет (как раз по справочникам): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584207/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-mysql

Comment: @Mike, последний, надеюсь на это, момент: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584282/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-mysql-final-battle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос был прост. Проблема состояла в том, что доселе, с вещами подобного рода не сталкивался. Как мне сказали в случае, если возникает необходимость ставить кавычки в кавычках их экранируют знаком \ посредством его размещения перед внутреними кавычками.

Comment: или обратный слеш, или повторной кавычкой, то есть две кавычки одинарные.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, благодарю