# Как изменить значение строки в таблице MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Показал все содержимое таблицы:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data;
```

Вывело:

```
    |config_id | scope | scope_id | patch                    | value
...
    |        81| stores|        2 | web/cookie/cookie_domain |.domain.ru
```

Как мне изменить или сделать пустым значение ".domain.ru" в 81 строке?

Comment: google: "mysql update"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'Ваше значение' WHERE config_id = '81';
```

Comment: mysql> UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '...' WHERE config_id = '81'
    -> 
Выводит такое почему-то знак ->  после команды и выйти не получается. Где моя ошибка, скажите, пожалуйста? Что если я хочу сделать это поле пустым?

Comment: @SergeyEremin Может у вас эта http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584060/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA проблема ?

Comment: Там речь про кавычки, а тут я готовую строку вставил. По идее ошибки не должно быть...

Comment: @SergeyEremin но стрелка может рисоваться только если вы не поставили после запроса точку с запятой или что то напутали в запросе с кавычками

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как из этой стрелки выйти опять к запросу?

Comment: @SergeyEremin смотря почему она появилась. поставить точку с запятой или сбалансировать кавычки

Comment: Благодарю! Действительно не хватало ;, насчёт гугла, гуглил, но там везде были совершенно другие примеры, сложно было понять принцип сходу для другого примера и применить к своей таблице.