# Как изменить значение строки в таблице MySQL через Update

Tags: mysql, update

Показал все содержимое таблицы:

SELECT * FROM core_config_data;

Вывело:

```
|id_filters|DisplayName0|razresheno
...
|1         |Print       |0
```

Как мне поменять значение 0 на 1, но обращаясь к Print 
Нашел вот такой ответ: [Как изменить значение строки в таблице MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-mysql) но там меняют просто значение, а мне нужно изменить поле "razresheno" зная только поле "DisplayName0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE core_config_data SET razresheno=1 WHERE DisplayName0='Print'

Если поле DisplayName0 не уникально, то обновятся все поля razresheno с данным значением. Меняйте структуру приложения

Comment: Спасибо большое