# Выбрать в 2 столбцах известные значения, заменить в выбраном на значение

Tags: sql

Помогите пожалуйста не могу написать банальный запрос (mysql) на замену значений в выбранном диапазоне командой SELECT.
Есть таблица crm_pics имеющая столбец user_sup и user_client и много других мне не нужных. В данных таблицах я выбираю SELECT * FROM `crm_pics` WHERE `user_sup` = 258 AND `user_client` != 3 После чего я хочу в этом выбранном заменить все значения в столбце user_client которые на равны 3 на значение допустим 75.

Comment: заменить где, в самой выборке или в таблице ? Если второе - то вам нужен update, а не select

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-mysql

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить значение строки в таблице MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585379/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался спасибо Mike не ту функцию выбрал

Запрос
UPDATE crm_pics SET user_client=75 WHERE user_sup = 258 AND user_client != 3