# Перезаписать значение в базе данных SQL

Tags: android, база-данных

Есть БД, в ней поля:

```
COLUMN_ID = "_id";
COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
COLUMN_CHECK = "Check";
```

Первые три поля пользователь изменять не может, четвертое имеет значение `0` или `1`, которые пользователь будет менять нажатием . Подскажите, как правильно перезаписывать изменением положения `toogle`
Не могу сообразить код для перезаписи значений

Comment: какое отношение метка android имеет к SQL ? если вопрос все таки касается именно sql, то изменение значений производиться запросом update https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585379/194569

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то у  `toogleButton` вроде есть что то типа `onCheckedChanged()`

Собственно :

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)      

//Состояние: Включён
//тут апдейтим по id базу данных и передаем в нужный столбец значение 1
MyData md = new MyData(_id, 1 //COLUMN_CHECK); 
mDBConnector.update(md);
        else
            //Состояние: Выключен
//тут делаем то же самое , только передаем значение 0
    }
```

какое то подобие запроса :

```
public int update(MyData md) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, md.getColumnCheck());
    return mDataBase.update(
            TABLE_NAME,
            cv,
            COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{
                    String.valueOf(md.getID()
                    )});
}
```

Тут полей у меня меньше, и запрос может требовать доработки но по сути вам нужен метод update. Если вся каша в RecyclerView, то педалим `ID` по `adapterPosition`
Ну и это старая `Java Classic`. Теперь есть удобный `ROOM` и даже `Котлин`, там вообще все просто, но суть та же.

Comment: Логика мне нравится, но что то студия ругается на синтаксис безбожно

Comment: @ru38irk потому что метод update вызывается в хелпере базы данных , классе DBConnectorили на край в ее классе так как лна необходима ему для работы

Comment: @ru38irk пример древний, но рабочий вроде

Comment: @ru38irk для того , что бы нормально ответить на ваш вопрос ВАМ нужно добавить некоторые вводные данные о том что вы делаете там у себя. Как получаете данные как выводите списком или еще как то и так далее